# Reply to email - dealing with the HTML

Tags: php, html, email, gmail-imap

I have a PHP script that checks Gmail for new mail, then depending on the conditions of the email, will reply to the email with some information.

My question is when replying to an HTML email, what is the best way to deal with the HTML? Should I find the position of where the  tag ends and then just insert my HTML code there after that?

I'm curious how an email client handles this when I hit Reply.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the client, sadly. I've had mixed results with Evolution, Thunderbird, Postler, etc.

Comment: do you want / need the HTML from the original email? you could always run a `strip_tags` on it.

Comment: I'd like to keep the original email as well. Best way I can tell to do this is find the start & end position of the <body> tag and replace my content right after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if the email contains a plain-text version of the email and reply to that.

Outside of that -- ignore "proper" html. Find the beginning of their email (be it `<html>` or `<p>`) Add your reply followed by `<hr /><strong>Original Message...etc` before that and be done.

Good luck

Comment: Yea that's what I figured would be the best way. Though it should be the beginning of the <body> not <html> right?

Comment: Regardless of the first tag -- You don't know whether their email client starts emails from `<html>` or not. It might not specify doctype, or html, or body tags at all.

Answer (score 0):

just want to share some of the problems that i had encountered with HTML email and have a few things that i always keep in mind:

- You'll need to put your css stylesheet inside the the body tag
  because Gmail ignore whatever outside the body tag.
- Make sure your CSS works in various email client platform.
- If your email height is more than 1497px (not 100% sure with the
  number, i've seen this in some article before) or else it will have
  unknown space gap in Outlook.